# Assembly instruction mov register,[register][register]

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, mov

I'm studying ASM 8086 theoretically on highschool (MASM, x86).

```
.data
var  dd   421,422, 443, 442, 444, 217, 432

.code
; some code
mov  esi, (OFFSET var)+4
mov  ebx, 4
mov  edx, [ebx][esi]   ; that's the line I don't uderstand
```

I ran that program and after that EDX == 000001BBh == 443
What's the meaning of last line in that code? What does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esi` points 4 bytes after var, which is `422`.
`ebx` is 4.

`[ebx][esi]` is something which denotes `[ebx+esi]` and the `[]` is a pointer operator.

All this together will make `[ebx][esi]` point yet 4 bytes farther than `422` and obviously `443` can be found there.