# Assembly code construction

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, masm, cpu-registers

My problem is an academic task I've been asigned: 
What will be the content of `edx` after this fragment of a program:

```
linie dd 421, 422, 443
      dd 442, 444, 427, 432

----------------
      mov esi, (OFFSET linie)+4
      mov ebx, 4
      mov edx, [ebx][esi]
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the meaning of `mov edx, [ebx][esi]`?
2. Why is there 000001bb in my `edx` after debugging the program?

Comment: This is homework. You should've done more research.

Comment: And it seems that this particular homwework was posted the last year, possibly by other student that had this task assigned last course :/ http://stackoverflow.com/q/9855299/3011009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `mov edx, [ebx] [esi]` means the same as `mov edx, [ebx + esi]` - it refers to the memory cell of adress which is the sum
of the `ebx` and `esi` registers.

There will be 443 (`1bb` in hex)in your `edx` register after completing the program. First, let's notice that in `linie` you define `dwords` 
which are 32-bit words.

```
 mov esi, (OFFSET linie)+4 ;sends the adress of the begining of the linie 
                           ;area plus 4 bytes(32 bits)
                           ; the esi will point to 422 in the linie array
 mov ebx, 4                ;simple asigning 4 to ebx
 mov edx, [ebx][esi]       ;move the content of a memory cell of 
                           ;adress 4+ the adress of 422
                           ; in other words - move the third element of the
                           ;linie array to edx.
```

Comment: Ok and how do we know that +4 refers to bytes and not dwords?

Comment: That's the way it's constructed - the memory cells are bytes

Comment: Because addresses and offsets are always specified with 1-byte granularity.

Comment: NP thats a good question actually:) the notation [reg][reg] is not so common

Answer (score 0):

```
  mov esi, (OFFSET linie)+4
  mov ebx, 4
  mov edx, [ebx][esi]
```

This will read the value from `[ebx + esi]`, i.e. `[linie+4+4]`. That corresponds to the third element of `linie` (since each element is `DWORD`, which on x86 is 4 bytes), and that element is 443 decimal == 0x1bb hexadecimal.